# Excel Quick Access Toolbar - change trigger keys

Tags: excel, vba, office365, ms-office, ribbonx

I have two questions about the Excel Quick Access toolbar. 1) Is it possible to change the shortcut sequence from e.g. ""Alt"" + ""1"", to ""Alt"" + ""&""? 2) My new employer gave me a 15inch laptop instead of a 13inch. This means that I have a dedicated number pad, which makes it impossible to access the QAT using two key strikes since the system does not detect my 1/& key as a 1. Instead I need to make an ""Alt + Shift + 1"" sequence now. (My keyboard language is AZERTY).

Anyone with an answer on either of the above questions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to specify your own. In your ribbon XML markup you need to use the `keytip` attribute or the `getKeytip` callback to specify the keyboard shortcut. Here is what MSDN states for that:

> KeyTips are the keyboard shortcuts that appear on the Ribbon when you press the ALT key. You can assign your own KeyTips by using the keytip and getKeytip attributes. (The getKeytip attribute supplies the name of a callback procedure that provides the KeyTip.)

The signature of the `getKeyTip` callback looks in the following way:

```
C#: string GetKeytip(IRibbonControl control)
VBA: Sub GetKeytip (control As IRibbonControl, ByRef label)
C++: HRESULT GetKeytip ([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval] BSTR *pbstrKeytip)
Visual Basic: Function GetKeytip (control As IRibbonControl) As String
```

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)